# Signing and Posting SAML file in C#

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement single sign on using SAML. The idp sent me request sample as below:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://client1.com/MyBank1/ReceiveSAMLResponse"
Destination=" https://tawtheeq.sa/identity-gateway/ReceiveSAMLRequest"
ForceAuthn="false" ID="9eff699e-6e2c-487c-940f-1f67c226f423" IsPassive="false"
IssueInstant="2018-02-05T07:49:14.992Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
Version="2.0">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"> https://client1.com/</saml:Issuer>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        ...
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>
        tKSzhWGSv...FPbhwPQ==
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDZz...tlak4=</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" />
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
    <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
    </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
```

They provided me also with their certificate .cer file to verify signature in response, .cer file that i can use as our .cer file, keystore password and alias name and keystore.jks file.

I created sample web project for testing, An empty page with one button on clicking on this button i am creating an X509Certificate2 object using our (SP) .cer file and creating testXML then signit and finally Post the request to the URL. Below are the code that i use.

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }


    protected void SendRequest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string RequestURL = "https://tawtheeq.sa:8443/identity-gateway-test/ReceiveSAMLRequest";
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"my-bank1-public.cer");

        XmlDocument xml = CreateSomeXml("textXML");
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var signedXml = SignDoc(xml, certificate, guid.ToString(), guid.ToString());

        PostXMLData(RequestURL, signedXml.ToString());

    }   
    public void PostXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        requestStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //Response.RedirectPermanent(response.ResponseUri.);
        //if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        //{
        //    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        //    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        //    return responseStr;
        //}
    }
    public static XmlElement SignDoc(XmlDocument doc, X509Certificate2 cert2, string referenceId, string referenceValue)
    {

        SamlSignedXml sig = new SamlSignedXml(doc, referenceId);
        // Add the key to the SignedXml xmlDocument. 
        sig.SigningKey = cert2.PrivateKey;

        // Create a reference to be signed. 
        Reference reference = new Reference();

        reference.Uri = String.Empty;
        reference.Uri = "#" + referenceValue;

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference. 
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new
            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
        XmlDsigC14NTransform env2 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();

        reference.AddTransform(env);
        reference.AddTransform(env2);

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object. 
        sig.AddReference(reference);

        // Add an RSAKeyValue KeyInfo
        // (optional; helps recipient find key to validate). 
        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfoX509Data keyData = new KeyInfoX509Data(cert2);

        keyInfo.AddClause(keyData);

        sig.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Compute the signature. 
        sig.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature
        // and save it to an XmlElement object. 
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = sig.GetXml();

        return xmlDigitalSignature;
    }

    public static XmlDocument CreateSomeXml(string FileName)
    {
        // Create a new XmlDocument object.
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();

        // Create a new XmlNode object.
        XmlNode node = document.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "", "MyElement", "samples");

        // Add some text to the node.
        node.InnerText = "Example text to be signed.";

        // Append the node to the document.
        document.AppendChild(node);

        // Save the XML document to the file name specified.
        XmlTextWriter xmltw = new XmlTextWriter(FileName, new UTF8Encoding(false));
        document.WriteTo(xmltw);
        xmltw.Close();
        return document;
    }
}

public class SamlSignedXml : SignedXml
{
    private string _referenceAttributeId = "";
    public SamlSignedXml(XmlDocument document,
                 string referenceAttributeId) : base(document)
    {
        _referenceAttributeId = referenceAttributeId;
    }
    public override XmlElement GetIdElement(
        XmlDocument document, string idValue)
    {
        return (XmlElement)
            document.SelectSingleNode(
                string.Format("//*[@{0}='{1}']",
                _referenceAttributeId, idValue));
    }
}
```

Signed XML from the code is not correct and it is not working when i try to post the file:

```
<SignedInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n- 
20010315" />
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
<Reference URI="">
 <Transforms>
  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped- 
signature" />
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<DigestValue>zSI5ZAMmQ+8u7R2rP7aAPT6nNQw=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">EncryptedKey</SignatureValue>
```

**Note:** I removed the encrypted key from signed xml.

My Questions are:

1. Is is the right why for this integration bcz this is my first time to work with SAML SSO.
2. What is the use of Keystore in this situation.
3. I'd appreciate it if you share with me any helpful article on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am looking for same.